# Якоря и ссылки на них

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт для скроллинга к якорю. Как сделать смену изображения, которое ведет к якорю, на который кликнул юзер ?

Например, я нажимаю на ссылку `#settings`, попадаю на `<div id="settings"></div>` и иконка меняет src.

Иконка - изображения: `<img src="images/[files|note|settings|pass|blog|info].png">`

Нужен эффект как [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window#scrollintoview) (слева в сайдбаре ссылки меняют цвет в зависимости от якоря)

Html:

```
<div class="leftb" style=" position: fixed; text-align:center;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 5%; padding-top:15%;
height: 100%; background: black;"><a href="#files"><img src="http://kottsov.ru/images/files.png"></a><br>
                                <a href="#note"><img src="http://kottsov.ru/images/note.png" style="margin-top:10px"></a><br>
                                <a href="#settings"><img src="http://kottsov.ru/images/settings.png" style="margin-top:10px"></a><br>                           
                                <a href="#pass"><img src="http://kottsov.ru/images/pass.png" style="margin-top:10px"></a><br>
                                <a href="#blog"><img src="http://kottsov.ru/images/blog.png" style="margin-top:10px"></a><br>   
                                <a href="#info"><img src="http://kottsov.ru/images/info.png" style="margin-top:10px"></a>
                                </div>

              <section id="files" style="background:red"></section>
              <section id="note" style="background:yellow"></section>
              <section id="settings" style="background:green"></section>
              <section id="pass" style="background:orange"></section>
              <section id="blog" style="background:black"></section>
              <section id="info" style="background:white"></section>
```

Js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".leftb").on("click","a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
        top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top-55}, 500);
});
});

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
     var $sections = $('section');
$sections.each(function(i,el){
    var top  = $(el).offset().top-100;
    var bottom = top +$(el).height();
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var id = $(el).attr('id');
    if( scroll > top && scroll < bottom){
    // менять изображение, класс которого соответствует якорю
    }
})
});
```

[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/6bz4x98c/)

Answer (score 1):

Все легко и просто как 2 + 2

```
$(function(){
    var $a = $('.leftb a');
    $a.on('click', function(){
        $a.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Классу **active** присваиваете цвет который Вам нужен и он окрасит Вам а-шку.